# In Chome devtools Performance, why is the FPS always showing 60fps with dropped frames, but actually it isn't

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, frame-rate

I'm studying [Analyze runtime performance](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) using the demo https://googlechrome.github.io/devtools-samples/jank/

When I open FPS meter (using Frame Rendering Stats in Rendering tab), it shows 10.8 fps:
[image]

However, when I record using Performance, there are lots of red blocks and a few green blocks. Every 20 red blocks, one green block. But in every block it shows 60 fps, **which is totally wrong**
[image]
[image]

As the red blocks are dropped, and I have noticed that during the 20 red blocks, the animation has never change. So I just imagine maybe the real value is 60 / 20 = 3 fps. This is reasonable as actually there are only 3 green blocks inside 1000ms. **But that is still not equal to 10.8 fps**. It really make me confused!

Supplement:
In the document it shows 12 fps([see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMl3Z.png)), but it doesn't show any red dropped frames. Maybe it is due to the dropped frames are brought in 2020(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-KP3fAjemdm7lnvCll9T1Lg-ikCzRPI-oNCp8fHAQCc/edit#heading=h.neguedjcao67), and the document is actually outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I tried https://googlechrome.github.io/devtools-samples/jank/ and set the CPU "6x slowdown" in the Performance tab. The animation became significantly janky, while the Frame Rate was still very close to 60 fps.

It seems that the FPS meter is not accurate.